# Export Classification and USML Lists

Tags: api, licensing, linked-data, trade

We are looking for Commerce Control List Export Classification Control Numbers and International Traffic and Arms United States Munitions List numbers in a table to upload into our ERP. It is currently free form and we are unable to collect internal data correctly. Prefer .xml or .csv file type.